# How can I reorder pipe delimited columns in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have delimited columns, like the example below, and want to swap the sequence of the components:

```
CHANGE FROM
candy:apple
lohbjk:Phjghnn
agikollp:LKnhg69

TO
apple:candy
Phjghnn:lohbjk
LKnhg69:agikollp
```

I tried this with notepad++:

```
Find: (.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*) Replace: \1|\3|\2
```

But that doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: Can you add specifically what you tried?

Comment: Find: (.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*)

Replace: \1|\3|\2

Comment: Why are you using `\|` when you have `:`?

Comment: i have no idea why i did that.

Comment: `:` is a colon. `|` is a pipe. Please fix either the title of the post or the body of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable regular expressions

Find: `^(.*?):(.*?)$`
Replace all: `\2:\1`

Comment: I see you have a lot of simple regular expression questions over the **past 4.5 years** on SuperUser.  I would highly recommend going through some online tutorials. It's easy! I promise!